# Why an implicit-conversion-sequence is not the best ICS if it's using a "Promotion"?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, implicit-conversion

Compiling this piece of code:

```
int func( int ) {
 return 1;
}
int func( char ) {
 return 2;
}
struct foo {
  operator int() { // Call to 'func(a)' is ambigous #1
  // operator char() { // Call to 'func(a)' is not ambigous #2
  return 1;
 }
 operator float() {
  return 0.f;
 }
};

int test_it (void) {
 foo a;
 return (func(a)==2);
}
```

if I define, for `foo`  the `int`-conversion operator instead of char, many compiler find the call `func(a)` ambiguous, only 1 compiler find it not ambiguous.

https://godbolt.org/g/zhRJZB

Reading the standard, I am not expecting that, because:

if I compile `#2` the struct `a` is converted from `foo -> char` and then `char -> char` this is the best implicit conversion sequence (ICS) of the candidate set made by:

```
(1) foo ->  char : char -> char
(2) foo ->  char : char -> int 
(3) foo ->  float : float -> int
(3) foo ->  float : float -> char
```

the conversion `char -> int` is a promotion so the rank of this conversion (2) is "Promotion" and it is worst than "Exact match" (1) , 
`float -> int` is a (3) "Conversion"

In case `#1` instead:

```
 foo ->  int : int -> int
```

should be the best ICS, because :

```
(1) foo ->  int : int -> int better than 
(3) foo ->  int : int -> char 
(3) foo ->  float : float -> int
(3) foo ->  float : float -> char
```

So in this candidate set, should be only implicit conversion sequence that is better than the other.

Can somebody explain me why the code should be ambiguous?

Answer (score 0):

Because overload resolution does not compare the four conversions directly.

In #2 case, overload resolution first assumes `int func(int)` is selected, then it finds

```
foo -> char  : char -> int is better than
foo -> float : float -> int
```

So the conversion `foo -> char  : char -> int` is taken into consideration if `int func(int)` is selected. Similarly, if `int func(char)` is selected, then it finds

```
foo -> char  : char -> char is better than
foo -> float : float -> char
```

So the conversion `foo -> char  : char -> char` is taken into consideration if `int func(char)` is selected. Finally, since

```
foo -> char  : char -> char is better than
foo -> char  : char -> int
```

Overload resolution finally chooses `int func(char)` as well as the conversion `foo -> char  : char -> char`.

---

#1 case is similar except overload resolution cannot determine which conversion to choose **when it assumes `int func(char)` is selected**. In such case, overload resolution introduces an *ambiguous conversion sequence* for the purpose of comparing the implicit conversion sequences corresponding to the two `func`'s (to determine which `func` to choose). Ambiguous conversion sequence is indistinguishable from any user-defined conversion sequence, so the result is ambigious.

Quoted from [[over.best.ics]/10](http://www.eel.is/c++draft/over.best.ics#10):

> If several different sequences of conversions exist that each convert the argument to the parameter type, the implicit conversion sequence associated with the parameter is defined to be the unique conversion sequence designated the *ambiguous conversion sequence*. For the purpose of ranking implicit conversion sequences as described in [over.ics.rank], the ambiguous conversion sequence is treated as a user-defined conversion sequence that is indistinguishable from any other user-defined conversion sequence.